# Azure Functions CosmosDB input binding using HTTP request userId value

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a basic azure function written in the JavaScript v4 programming model. I want it to use the user id available from the http request to go to the database and get a document representing the user's details. The below returns a 500 server error as request is undefined outside the handler.

```
const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
  databaseName: 'rcmapp',
  collectionName: 'users',
  id: '{request.user.id}',
  partitionKey: '{request.user.id}',
  connectionStringSetting: 'COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING'
});

app.http('userDetails', {
  methods: ['GET'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
  handler: (request, context) => {
    context.log(`User details function triggered`);
    const userDetails = JSON.parse(context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput));

    return {
      body: userDetails
    };
  }
});
```

Is there a way I can access this value to pass to the input binding using a binding expression?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code to *fetch the user details by passing the* **user_Id** as a parameter to the Http request.

```js
const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
  databaseName: 'userdetails',
  containerName: 'usercontainer',
  id: '{Query.id}',
  partitionKey: '{Query.user_id}',
  connection: 'cosmosconnection'
});

app.http('userDetails', {
  methods: ['GET','POST'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
  handler: (request, context) => {
    context.log(`User details function triggered`);
    const userDetails = context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput);

    return {
      body: `Found user details with id ${userDetails.user_name}`,
    };
  }
});
```

- Created a **Cosmos DB Container** and added `/user_id` as **partition key**.
- Uploaded a Json file having the **user_details**.

[image]

**Running the function in local:**

[image]

- Passing the parameter **user_id** and **id**:

[image]